# How to make Ansible execute a shell script if a package is not installed

Tags: ansible

How can I make Ansible execute a shell script if a (rpm) package is not installed? Is it somehow possible to leverage the yum module?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I don't think the yum module would help in this case.  It currently has 3 states: absent, present, and latest.  Since it sounds like you don't want to actually install or remove the package (at least at this point) then you would need to do this in two manual steps.  The first task would check to see if the package exists, then the second task would invoke a command based on the output of the first command.

If you use "rpm -q" to check if a package exists then the output would look like this for a package that exists:

```
# rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
```

and like this if the package doesn't exist:

```
# rpm -q httpdfoo
package httpdfoo is not installed
```

So your ansible tasks would look something like this:

```
- name: Check if foo.rpm is installed
  command: rpm -q foo.rpm
  register: rpm_check

- name: Execute script if foo.rpm is not installed
  command: somescript
  when: rpm_check.stdout.find('is not installed') != -1
```

The rpm command will also exit with a 0 if the package exists, or a 1 if the package isn't found, so another possibility is to use:

```
when: rpm_check.rc == 1
```

Comment: The problem with the command is, if `rpm -q` exits with 0 (no package found), the playbook will fail. To prevent that append: `ignore_errors: True` to the task in order to use the output in subsequent tasks to install the rpm.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to add `changed_when: no` to force the `command` module not to say something has changed.

Comment: Also, to avoid the failure message when the package is not found you can set `failed_when: rpm_check.rc > 1`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `failed_when: rpm_check.rc = 1` I tried this and on a failed RPM `rc` is always set to 1. I haven't seen a number higher than 1.

Comment: I tired it get this working using with_items but it doesn't seem to work  http://serverfault.com/questions/747577/how-can-i-use-stdout-within-an-ansible-conditional-correctly

Comment: With `ignore_errors: yes` it still counts as an error, so `failed_when: no` seems like a better option.

Comment: You can run tasks in check mode to avoid side effects. You can use yum module for this... Check my answer.

Answer (score 33):

Based on the Bruce P answer above, a similar approach for apt/deb files is

```
- name: Check if foo is installed
  command: dpkg-query -l foo
  register: deb_check

- name: Execute script if foo is not installed
  command: somescript
  when: deb_check.stdout.find('no packages found') != -1
```

Comment: I needed to add `failed_when: False`

Comment: I'd like to point out that as of Ansible 2.1, the apt module has an option called `only_upgrade`, which is designed precisely for this end. The documentation describes the switch: 'Only install/upgrade a package if it is already installed.'

Comment: @Erathiel I think what this playbook solves is run a "certain" task if the given package is found. So not necessarily about install a missing package, it could be something else. That `only_upgrade` option is for making sure the package is either installed or updated much like what happens with `state`.

Comment: @Erathiel The OP wants an if/then test. He/she doesn't state that they want to actually install anything. Cheers.

Comment: And add `changed_when: False` if you want this to be idempotent.

Answer (score 28):

If the package is installable through the system package manager (yum, apt, etc) itself, then you can make use of the check mode flag of ansible to register installation status without actually installing the package.

```
- name: check if package is installed
  package:
    name: mypackage
    state: present
  check_mode: true
  register: mypackage_check

- name: run script if package installed
  shell: myscript.sh
  when: not mypackage_check.changed
```

Comment: By using the `package` module instead of the specific `yum` one, this would make it the best answer as it would be working on more than RHEL or Debian family of Linux distributions. Well done!

Comment: This didn't work for me. If the package is not installed, Ansible errors out. I had to add "ignore_errors: yes" to the "check if package is installed" section.

Comment: What ansible version? 2.3.2.0 is known to err out when you install from an RPM file. It got fixed with 2.4.0.0.

Comment: When the package is not installed, the task `check if package is installed` reports a failure, when in fact it has run successfully and registered the variable `mypackage_check` <--- this variable is defined and is available to be used in successive tasks. I used a similar approach to the workaround invoked in the comment by @JesseAdelman: I added [`failed_when: False`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) to the end of the `check if package is installed` task.

Answer (score 25):

Related to this.

Putting everything together, complete playbook for `Debian` (Ubuntu) which Updates package only if it's already installed:

```
---
- name: Update package only if already installed (Debian)
  hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Check if Package is installed
      shell: dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' {{ package }} | grep 'install ok installed'
      register: is_installed
      failed_when: no
      changed_when: no

    - name: Update Package only if installed
      apt:
        name: {{ package }}
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
      when: is_installed.rc == 0
```

Sadly Ansible still hasn't built-in support for making simple package updating, see ex: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10856

Comment: As [noted below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36405647/2192488), using `shell: dpkg --status {{ package }} |grep 'install ok installed'` is more robust than using `command: dpkg-query -l {{ package }}`.

Answer (score 24):

Since Ansible 2.5, you can use the [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/package_facts_module.html) module:

```
- name: Gather package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: auto

- name: Debug if package is present
  debug:
    msg: 'yes, mypackage is present'
  when: '"mypackage" in ansible_facts.packages'

- name: Debug if package is absent
  debug:
    msg: 'no, mypackage is absent'
  when: '"mypackage" not in ansible_facts.packages'
```

Note: you need the python bindings for apt/rpm installed on the target, e.g. `python-apt` for Debian.

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't be using `dpkg -l package` because it has no idea if your package has been removed or is still installed.
Instead it's probably better to use `dpkg -s package`.

To check if the package is installed :
- `shell: dpkg -s package | grep 'install ok installed'`
or if you don't mind the package on hold or other states :
- `shell: dpkg -s package | grep 'installed'`
This return 0 when installed and 1 if not.

(It's important to use the shell as we are using a pipe `|`)

Comment: i had to change it to `shell: dpkg -s package | grep -c 'install ok installed'` in my case on Debian grep didn't return 0 or 1. With the `-c` option it returns the number of lines found.

Answer (score 2):

I find using shell or command module is not "ansiblic".

I prefer to use yum module and [json_query](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter to check if a package is already installed. E.g. httpd package :

```
    - yum:
        list: httpd
      register: apache_service

    - assert:
        that:
          - "'installed' in apache_service|json_query('results[*].yumstate')"
      msg: 'httpd is not installed'
```