# How would I confirm that a python package is installed using ansible

Tags: python, pip, conditional-statements, ansible, virtualenv

I am writing an [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) playbook, and I would first like to install [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew), and transition into that pew environment in order to install some other python libraries.

So, my playbook is going to look something like this...

```
tasks:

# task 1
- name: install pew if necessary
  command: pip install pew

# task 2
- name: create new pew environment if necessary
  command: pew new devpi-server

# task 3
- name: transition to pew environment
  command: pew workon devpi-server

# task 4
- name: install devpi-server
  command: pip install devpi-server

# task 5
- name: run devpi server
  command: devpi-server ## various args
```

In the spirit of keeping my playbook idempotent, I would like to do all of these tasks only if necesary.

So, I would only want to install pew if it isn't already installed, only want to create a new pew environment if it doesn't already exist, only workon the pew environment if we aren't already... etc etc...

Does anyone have good advice as to how to accomplish this? I am somewhat familiar with ansible conditionals, but only when it is something like, "is a file downloaded or not"

I haven't had to determine yet if programs are installed, virtual environments are loaded, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) in Ansible to ensure that certain packages are installed.

For your conditionals I would refer to: [How to make Ansible execute a shell script if a package is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892603/how-to-make-ansible-execute-a-shell-script-if-a-package-is-not-installed) and http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables - these should get you on the right track.

So your playbook would look a little like:

```
- pip: name=pew

- name: Check if pew env exists
  command: pew command
  register: pew_env_check

- name: Execute script if pew environment doesn't exist
  command: somescript
  when: pew_env_check.stdout.find('no packages found') != -1
```

Comment: I noticed the pip module as well. What would be your advice if I don't have pip installed on the remote machine. Curl get-pip.py and then run it? That's my current strategy.

Comment: If you have `easy_install` you could install it via that: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/easy_install_module.html

Comment: I don't have that either, and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501086/getting-msg-failed-to-find-required-executable-easy-install-when-trying-to-br) seems to indicate I shouldn't use it.

Comment: Ah - fair enough. Then I would go with your approach and add a check to see if pip is installed, if not, run your conditional and install it via curl.

Comment: Sweet. I think this is enough to get me started. I'll circle back and give you the accept once I've confirmed it all works. Thanks!

Comment: Still running into a few issues getting the entire script to run, but this is a solid enough of an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ansible tasks - Here are some examples:**

```
- name: Install bottle python package
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: bottle

- name: Install bottle python package on version 0.11
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: bottle==0.11

- name: Install bottle python package with version specifiers
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: bottle>0.10,<0.20,!=0.11

- name: Install multi python packages with version specifiers
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name:
      - django>1.11.0,<1.12.0
      - bottle>0.10,<0.20,!=0.11
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html